# Use wheel event to change classes

Tags: javascript

I want the use the wheel event to trigger a change in color of an element. The change in colour happens by cycling through classes. The class change should only happen at difference larger 50 in the deltaY so greater than 50 or lower than -50. The interaction should feel like one swipe changes to the next colour, therefore, the class change should only happen at the largest difference in delta or the 'peak' and conversely 'trough' and the bottom. I have outlined a peak below.

```
delta: 1
delta: 6
delta: 21
delta: 42
delta: 48
delta: 67
delta: 77
delta: 79    <————— HERE
delta: 77
delta: 75
delta: 72
delta: 70
delta: 66
delta: 64
delta: 59
delta: 55
delta: 51
delta: 47
delta: 45
delta: 41
delta: 37
delta: 35
delta: 32
delta: 29
delta: 26
delta: 24
delta: 22
delta: 20
delta: 19
delta: 17
delta: 16
delta: 14
delta: 13
delta: 12
delta: 11
delta: 10
delta: 9
delta: 8
delta: 7
delta: 6
delta: 5
delta: 4
delta: 3
delta: 2
delta: 1
```

Currently it works like:

```
delta: 1
delta: 6
delta: 21
delta: 42
delta: 48
delta: 67    <————— HERE
delta: 77    <————— HERE
delta: 79    <————— HERE
delta: 77    <————— HERE
delta: 75    <————— HERE...
delta: 72
delta: 70
delta: 66
delta: 64
delta: 59
delta: 55
delta: 51
delta: 47
delta: 45
delta: 41
delta: 37
delta: 35
delta: 32
delta: 29
delta: 26
delta: 24
delta: 22
delta: 20
delta: 19
delta: 17
delta: 16
delta: 14
delta: 13
delta: 12
delta: 11
delta: 10
delta: 9
delta: 8
delta: 7
delta: 6
delta: 5
delta: 4
delta: 3
delta: 2
delta: 1
```

How can I implement this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('main')
const classes = ['white', 'black', 'purple', 'blue', 'orange']

let index = 0
let lastDelta
let topDelta

function changeColour(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(`delta: ${event.deltaY}`)
    // console.log(`index: ${index}`)
    if (event.deltaY > 50) {
        if (index === index.length - 1) {
            index = 0
        } else {
            index++
        }
        container.classList = classes[index]
    } else if (event.deltaY < -50) {
        if (index === 0) {
            index = index.length - 1
        } else {
            index++
        }
        container.classList = classes[index]
    } else {
        event.deltaY = 0
    }

}

container.addEventListener('wheel', changeColour)
```

```css
main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<main>

</main>
```

Comment: You cannot do it at `79` because by then you don't know whether the next ones will be smaller and that you've hit the maximum.